# custom uitableviewcell with multiple devider views in it?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, multiple-columns

I had an iPad landscape application which had a spreadsheet like structure.For that i am using uitableview with custom cell with 6 devider views of width 1 and height of that of the cell.But the issue is one column had a different width.So auto layout is giving me hard time .Can anybody help me on how i can achieve this with constraints ?

Comment: You should write necessary information like your configuration of your tableview and your constraints that you have set!

Comment: I am just want to have a tableviewcell with 6 dividers for iPad landscape screen